# How to customiez WordPress dashboard js/css path

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello dear Stackoverflower, I got this question when configure a CDN to my site.

The CDN I use in site's main domain, has a  maximum request times per minutes, so if a user login to dashboard, they may quickly reach this threshold value due to lots of js/css file requests.

To solve this, I considered use another domain for dashboard, and configured in `wp-config.php` like this:

```
$home = 'https://main.domain';
$siteurl = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
define('WP_HOME', $home);
define('WP_SITEURL', $siteurl);
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', $siteurl);
define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', $siteurl);
define('WP_INCLUDES_URL', $siteurl);
define('WP_ADMIN_URL', $siteurl);
```

But I found this still not work with the css/js path, even if I visit though the new domain, they are still from the main domain.

My hope is to solve in one of these two ways:

1. Forcing the css/js path to be relative paths which match the current using domain;
2. There are some plugins like WP-Autoptimize to optimize js/css, is there any way to make them work in background as well? (In this case, reducing the request times from CDN is also OK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emmm, no one answer me since two days past by...

I got a better way, doing noting on WordPress, but with Nginx - proxy my site under another domain.

The is a Nginx module [ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module](https://github.com/yaoweibin/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module)

After compiling it in Nginx, you can use the conf below:

```
server_name proxy.domain;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://main.domain;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    subs_filter https://main.domain https://proxy.domain ir;
    subs_filter https://cdn.main.domain https://cdn.proxy.domain ir;
}
```

The key is the use of `subs_filter`.

Actually, with this module, I made a Google proxy: https://note.shino.cc/, really interesting ugh?